# Output related query for swapping of strings

Tags: c, pointers, swap

The output is "hello, world". I tried to map out what is happening in the code and have attached an image [showing what the function should be doing according to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKQfM.jpg). However I don't understand why the final output is coming out like that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char *p, char **q)
{
    char *temp = p;
    p = q;
    q = temp;
}

int main()
{
    char *p ="hello";
    char *q ="world";
    func(p,&q);
    printf("%s, %s", p, q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn warnings of your compiler on!

Comment: Your func does nothing since you only update the (local) arguments. On a side note you assign q which is a char** with temp which is a char*

Comment: A few things I would like to point out: (i) As Paul Ogilvie points out my compiler is indeed throwing some warnings but this isn't some code that I am writing. This was a question in an exam and we had to trace the output. (ii) I have tried to do so in the image I attached. So it would be really cool if you can point out where am I going wrong with the image in reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to pass by reference to swap the strings around, and are using pointers to do so - that's the correct way to do it! However, since this is a string in C, *your actual variables are pointers*. These pointer addresses are being passed (and swapped) by value. Indeed, if you place a print function inside `func`, you'll see that the strings are printed in the reverse order you're expecting.

```c
void func(char *p, char *q)
{
    char *temp = p;
    p = q;
    q = temp;
    printf("%s, %s", p, q);
}

int main()
{
    char *p ="hello";
    char *q ="world";
    func(p,q);
    printf("%s, %s", p, q);
    return 0;
}
```

`world, hellohello, world`

If you want to swap two variables, you need only pass their pointers and swap them - but if you want to swap the *pointers themselves,* you need to pass references to the pointers.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char **p, char **q)
{
    char *temp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = temp;
}

int main()
{
    char *p ="hello";
    char *q ="world";
    func(&p,&q);
    printf("%s, %s", p, q);
    return 0;
}
```

`world, hello`

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/SilverBonyProduct)

Comment: Your second sentence is confusing. Pointers are also variables and their values can also be swapped.

Comment: Good point. I'll try and think of a less confusing way to rewrite it - I'm open to suggestions if you have any.

Comment: Thank you for that but I would really like to trace the 'faulty' code rather than the correct code. If you look at the image I attached and point out where I am wrong then it would be great. (I think the second pointer 'q' is really getting updated with the address of 'h')

Comment: The code is in error because the values you're sending are lost when the function goes out of scope. If you somehow managed to return the values, your code would have undefined behavior, since `p` would point to the location of the actual pointer address `q`, and `q` would point to the start of `p`'s array.

Comment: Got it. The 'p' in the function is a local variable so any updation in it isn't reflected in the main func. The local q is a pointer to the pointer q in main but when the printf is being done in main it takes it's local q rather than the function's local q. I hope this is accurate.